# OSError: No translation files found for default language zh_Hans

Tags: python, django, translation, default, django-i18n

django: 1.10.3
local: windows
server: debian

local can run normally, can not run in my server, but can run by `en-us`, why, I can't run by `zh_hans`?

Traceback:

```
      ...File "/home/a/ENV/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/translation/__init__.py", line 85, in ugettext
        return _trans.ugettext(message)
      File "/home/a/ENV/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/translation/trans_real.py", line 337, in gettext
        return do_translate(message, 'gettext')
      File "/home/a/ENV/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/translation/trans_real.py", line 320, in do_translate
        _default = _default or translation(settings.LANGUAGE_CODE)
      File "/home/a/ENV/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/translation/trans_real.py", line 227, in translation
        _translations[language] = DjangoTranslation(language)
      File "/home/a/ENV/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/translation/trans_real.py", line 134, in __init__
        raise IOError("No translation files found for default language %s." % settings.LANGUAGE_CODE)
    OSError: No translation files found for default language zh_Hans.
```

updata: settings.py

```html
"""
Django settings for aWebsite project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 1.10.3.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/settings/
"""

import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'a*x^k((1zswa$g_qu70f%%8mb6z7p1tfzy%&+@kye+3zdafv3h'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = False
TEMPLATE_DEBUG = False

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['aWebsite.com']


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'grappelli',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'ckeditor',
    'ckeditor_uploader',
    'imagekit',
    'Website',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'aWebsite.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')]
        ,
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'hitekCable.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'sdefg.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/i18n/

#LANGUAGE_CODE = 'zh_Hans'
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'Asia/Shanghai'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = 'http:/aWebsite.com/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'collected_static')

STATICFILES_DIRS = [(os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'Website/static'))]

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = 'http://aWebsite.com/media_hitek/'


CKEDITOR_UPLOAD_PATH = "uploads/"  
CKEDITOR_UPLOAD_SLUGIFY_FILENAME = True
CKEDITOR_ALLOW_NONIMAGE_FILES = False
CKEDITOR_RESTRICT_BY_USER = True
CKEDITOR_IMAGE_BACKEND = 'pillow' 
CKEDITOR_JQUERY_URL = '//cdn.bootcss.com/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js'
CKEDITOR_CONFIGS = {
    'default': {
        'skin': 'moono',
        # 'skin': 'office2013',
        'toolbar_Basic': [
            ['Source', '-', 'Bold', 'Italic']
        ],
        'toolbar_YourCustomToolbarConfig': [
            {'name': 'document', 'items': ['Source', '-', 'Print', '-', 'Templates']},#'Save', 'NewPage', 'Preview',
            {'name': 'clipboard', 'items': ['Cut', 'Copy', 'Paste', 'PasteText', 'PasteFromWord', '-', 'Undo', 'Redo']},
            {'name': 'editing', 'items': ['Find', 'Replace', '-', 'SelectAll']},
            {'name': 'forms',
             'items': ['Form', 'Checkbox', 'Radio', 'TextField', 'Textarea', 'Select', 'Button', 'ImageButton',
                       'HiddenField']},
            '/',
            {'name': 'basicstyles',
             'items': ['Bold', 'Italic', 'Underline', 'Strike', 'Subscript', 'Superscript', '-', 'RemoveFormat']},
            {'name': 'paragraph',
             'items': ['NumberedList', 'BulletedList', '-', 'Outdent', 'Indent', '-', 'Blockquote', 'CreateDiv', '-',
                       'JustifyLeft', 'JustifyCenter', 'JustifyRight', 'JustifyBlock', '-', 'BidiLtr', 'BidiRtl',
                       'Language']},
            {'name': 'links', 'items': ['Link', 'Unlink', 'Anchor']},
            {'name': 'insert',
             'items': ['Image', 'Flash', 'Table', 'HorizontalRule', 'Smiley', 'SpecialChar', 'PageBreak', 'Iframe']},
            # '/',
            {'name': 'styles', 'items': ['Styles', 'Format', 'Font', 'FontSize']},
            {'name': 'colors', 'items': ['TextColor', 'BGColor']},
            {'name': 'tools', 'items': ['Maximize', 'ShowBlocks']},
            # {'name': 'about', 'items': ['About']},
            # '/',  # put this to force next toolbar on new line
            # {'name': 'yourcustomtools', 'items': [
            #     # put the name of your editor.ui.addButton here
            #     'Preview',
            #     'Maximize',
            #
            # ]},
        ],
        'toolbar': 'YourCustomToolbarConfig',  # put selected toolbar config here
        # 'toolbarGroups': [{ 'name': 'document', 'groups': [ 'mode', 'document', 'doctools' ] }],
        # 'height': 291,
        # 'width': '100%',
        # 'filebrowserWindowHeight': 725,
        # 'filebrowserWindowWidth': 940,
        # 'toolbarCanCollapse': True,
        # 'mathJaxLib': '//cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/2.2-latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS_HTML',
        'tabSpaces': 4,
        'extraPlugins': ','.join(
            [
                # your extra plugins here
                'div',
                'autolink',
                'autoembed',
                'embedsemantic',
                'autogrow',
                # 'devtools',
                'widget',
                'lineutils',
                'clipboard',
                'dialog',
                'dialogui',
                'elementspath'
            ]),
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you share your settings file?

Comment: Yes, you can seeing now.

Comment: Okay, if you are going to use zh_Hans as a default language you will need to provide translation files for same. There are few variables that you need to set up in your settings file to let Django to know where to look for translation files and few more. Go through docs, and follow steps mentioned there.

Answer (score 4):

You should use:

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'zh-hans'

Also when you use django-admin makemessages -l zh_hans

Note: one is zh-hans, one is zh_hans.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error below:

> OSError: No translation files found for default language hello.

When I set `hello` to [LANGUAGE_CODE](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/settings/#language-code) and [LANGUAGES](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/settings/#languages) in `settings.py` as shown below. *I'm learning [Translation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/i18n/translation/) with **Django 4.2.1**:

```py
# "settings.py"

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'hello'

from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _

LANGUAGES = (
    ('hello', _('Hello')),
)
```

So, I ran [makemessages](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/django-admin/#makemessages) below but I couldn't solve the error:

```
django-admin makemessages -l hello
```

So, I ran [compilemessages](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/django-admin/#compilemessages) below, then I could solve the error:

```
django-admin compilemessages
```

But, I got another error below and I could not solve the error with several solutions:

> ValueError: invalid token in plural form: EXPRESSION

Finally, I found [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59156630/translation-e004-you-have-provided-a-value-for-the-language-code-setting-that-i#answer-59157763) below saying:

> You should use LANGUAGE_CODE exactly as mentioned in LANGUAGES list
> located in `django/conf/global_settings.py`

So, I should set the languages listed in `LANGUAGES` in [django/conf/global_settings.py](https://github.com/django/django/blob/main/django/conf/global_settings.py) to `LANGUAGE_CODE` and `LANGUAGES` in `settings.py`.