# translation.E004) You have provided a value for the LANGUAGE_CODE setting that is not in the LANGUAGES setting

Tags: django-settings

I've just reimaged my computer, so setting everything back up for my django project, and on running the server, I get this error. I haven't a clue what it is referring to as my original site came out of the box and as I speak English and this site is an internal work site, there is no reason to do anything language based. Does anyone know what this is or how to get past it so I can carry on working? Looking in the settings file, I have this for the Internationalization section:

```
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-GB'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True

DATE_INPUT_FORMATS = [
    '%Y-%m-%d', '%m/%d/%Y', '%m/%d/%y', # '2006-10-25', '10/25/2006', '10/25/06'
    '%d %b %Y', '%d %b, %Y',            # '25 Oct 2006', '25 Oct, 2006'
    '%d %B %Y', '%d %B, %Y',            # '25 October 2006', '25 October, 2006'
]
```

Is this the out of the box English code? if not, could someone tell me what is should be so I can set it back please, I can't find the outofthebox settings in the documentation.

Comment: I had the same issue, I set my LANGUAGE_CODE to "fr-fr", which doesn't exist in the LANGUAGES list. It's just "fr".

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In **Django 3.0** you should use LANGUAGE_CODE **exactly** as mentioned in LANGUAGES list located in [django/conf/global_settings.py](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/conf/global_settings.py)

The list is a list of two-tuples in the format (**language code**, **language name**) – for example, ('ja', 'Japanese'). This specifies which languages are available for language selection.

So, in your case, it will be LANGUAGE_CODE = '**en-gb**'

Comment: Thankyou very much, this has just highlighted also that I have installed django 3 but my site runs django 2.1.4. Looking at the docs and at the current time of writing, django3 was released as the official version yesterday, December 2 2019. Ok, I have a bit of work to do.

Comment: While this isn't necessarily to do with the title of the post, I think it is appropriate to point out one other change that stopped my site working from django 2.1.4 to django 3.0.0 is the template tag {% load staticfiles %} has now been changed to {% load static %}. Django does kindly tell you that but I missed it until @dtar solved my original issue.  The settings file still needs 'django.contrib.staticfiles' in the installed apps, that hasn't changed.

Comment: Thx, but why this change is not announced in [_release notes_](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/releases/3.0/)?

Answer (score 3):

For French-speaking people, you have to change **'fr-fr'** to **'fr'**