# Using a custom language gives "You have provided a value for the LANGUAGE_CODE setting that is not in the LANGUAGES setting."

Tags: python, django

I've just upgraded my Django project from 2.2 to 3.2 and the language broke.

I had this piece of code which was working fine (inside my settings.py)

```
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'tb' 

EXTRA_LANG_INFO = {
    'tb': {
        'bidi': False,
        'code': 'tb',
        'name': 'English',
        'name_local': 'United States',
        'fallback': ['en-US'],
    },
}

import django.conf.locale
LANG_INFO = dict(**django.conf.locale.LANG_INFO, **EXTRA_LANG_INFO)
django.conf.locale.LANG_INFO = LANG_INFO
```

Now I get

```
?: (translation.E004) You have provided a value for the LANGUAGE_CODE setting that is not in the LANGUAGES setting.
```

Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

Thanks.

Comment: You're trying to tell django to use the `tb` locale, which either doesn't exist or isn't installed on your system. `locale -a` should tell you what locales are available on your system.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [translation.E004) You have provided a value for the LANGUAGE\_CODE setting that is not in the LANGUAGES setting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59156630/translation-e004-you-have-provided-a-value-for-the-language-code-setting-that-i)

Comment: @joanis unfortunately, no

Answer (score 0):

Because of the updates that happened to Django, you also need to have a LANGUAGES list, as such:

```
LANGUAGES = [
    ('tb', 'English')
]
```

That's what fixed it for me.